# How to find a PDB structure of a protease with a peptide like inhibitor

Tags: pdb

I wonder how, for purposes of just illustrating some concepts like substrate alignment in the catalytic triad active site, I can quickly and efficiently find a protease structure (irrelevant of what organism exactly) that has a peptide like inhibitor on the PDB database.

Hints appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a Google search expert but "pdb structure protease peptide inhibitor -non-peptide" seems to provide some useful hits

Answer (score 1):

Here's one: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2IPH. It was crystallized with the inhibitor bound to the protein.

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: I searched within the pdb for protease inhibitor. Since the inhibitors themselves are not proteins, most of the search results are proteases with inhibitors.

Answer (score 0):

go to http://www.uniprot.org and enter the protease accession number you are interested in and look at the 3D structure databases section to see if its PDB file is deciphered or not. I came across this database (http://www.cf.ac.uk/biosi/staffinfo/ehrmann/tools/proteases/allproteases.html) just by typing into google "protease PDB databases"